# The name of an ejaculation in direct speech

Tags: single-word-requests

Sometimes, when writing direct speech or a dialogue, there is a scenario where someone will respond with a word or a few words, that do not constitute a full sentence (no subject and no finite verb).

For example:

Person 1: "You can't do that."

Person 2: "**Damn**!"

The response given by person 2 is not a sentience. And yet, in direct speech, that is sometimes necessary to preserve the flow of regular speech.

**Does that sort of language usage have a name to describe it?**

Comment: 'Interjection'?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This type of speech is called an '**interjection**', not an 'ejaculation'. Here is [a link that may help](http://grammar.yourdictionary.com/parts-of-speech/interjections/what-is-an-interjection.html).

Comment: I've always known an ejaculation to be a forcefully spoken word or phrase in direct speech. I put that in the question-title as a descripter.

Comment: @KittenWithAWhip You are right -- that is (or was) one of _ejaculation_'s meanings (see first sense for both US/UK at [dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/ejaculation). QI once spent several minutes establishing that [Dr. Watson ejaculated twice as often as Sherlock Holmes](http://qi.com/infocloud/sherlock-holmes). _Interjection_, though, is the word I'd use nowadays.

Comment: AHHH-kay. I picked up that usage of 'ejaculation' in Wuthering Heights. So the "Was" make sense.

Comment: @KittenWithAWhip Using 'ejaculation' nowadays, in this context, mostly just makes people giggle

Comment: True. Actually, it sticks in my mind because the line in _Wuthering Heights_ made me giggle. If I recall, it was 'Damn! He ejaculated' and I had a very innocent (and ignorant) English teacher.