# What is the proper name for idiomatic, exclamative phrases?

Tags: single-word-requests, idioms, exclamations

I'm wondering what the proper term would be for exclamations like "Hell's bells!", "Billions of blue blistering barnacles!", and "By Lucifer's Beard!". Specifically, I'm wondering about phrases, uttered either in amazement or under some kind of stress, and that are idiomatic (in the sense that the words themselves do not convey the meaning without context). Is there an actual English term for such utterances?

I'd prefer a single term to describe them, but a phrase would do. I would like something a little less of a mouthful than "idiomatic exclamation", and hopefully in wider usage.

Comment: If the expression is a modified curse, then you might call it a "minced oath."

Comment: ALSO [The name of an ejaculation in direct speech](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/403873/the-name-of-an-ejaculation-in-direct-speech/403874#403874).

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Why close a question with a closed question? Can you edit and find another question to add?

Comment: @Mari-LouA How much time do you spend trying to keep the site reasonably tidy?

Comment: @EdwinAshworth, you're right. I spend far too much time.

Comment: ;-). But to answer your question: I often find that closed questions are less contestably (and I get a lot of contest, assuming it's been massified) duplicates, pre-empting a lot of the 'WRONG! Re-open' retorts. And sometimes, I feel the closed dupes are the better questions and/or have the better answers. And on occasion, I feel the closed 'dupes' shouldn't have been closed. And sometimes, I feel the dupes kept should have been closed. Perhaps sometimes, I get it wrong. Or nod off.

Answer (score 3):

I would call them [***expletives***](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/expletive), though expletives are usually thought of as being 'swear words' and two of your examples are rather unusual!